# iterating for a beautifulsoup resultset python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am working on scraping data off a website (http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/players/8800/) and to do so I am using urllib2 and BeautifulSoup. My code at the moment looks like this:

```
site=  'http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/players/8800/'
response = urllib2.urlopen(site)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
rushing=[]
passing=[]
receiving=[]

#here is where my problem arises
for elem in soup.find_all('th', text=re.compile('2008')):
        passing = elem.parent.find_all('td', class_=re.compile('10'))
        rushing = elem.parent.find_all('td', class_=re.compile('20'))
        receiving = elem.parent.find_all('td', class_=re.compile('30'))
```

There are three instances where the soup.find_all(...'2008')) portion exists on this page, and each of these turn up when that portion is printed separately. Running this for loop, though, runs the loop only once. How can I make sure that the loop runs three times?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you need to [`extend()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) the lists you've defined before the loop:

```
rushing = []
passing = []
receiving = []

for elem in soup.find_all('th', text=re.compile('2008')):
    passing.extend([td.text for td in elem.parent.find_all('td', class_=re.compile('10'))])
    rushing.extend([td.text for td in elem.parent.find_all('td', class_=re.compile('20'))])
    receiving.extend([td.text for td in elem.parent.find_all('td', class_=re.compile('30'))])

print passing
print rushing
print receiving
```

Prints:

```
[u'3']
[u'19', u'58', u'14.5', u'3.1', u'0']
[u'2', u'17', u'4.3', u'8.5', u'11', u'6.5', u'0']
```